# is there a way to have a multi colored tab bar in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, tabs

Hi I'm still new to flutter and been studying it for about a week now, I'm currently creating an app that organizes funds for budgeting, I'm attempting to create a multi colored tab bar so users can easily identify their funds, I tried searching over the net and read the tab documentation but still no luck, any tips?

~edit

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the background color of each tab bar same as the background color of scaffold, the default background color of tab bar is currently grey, it should be red on the first tab, blue on second tab, yellow on third tab. is it possible?

here's a screenshot in the emulator:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTaau.png)

here are sample of my code:

/main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './FirstTab.dart' as first;
import './SecondTab.dart' as second;
import 'ThirdTab.dart' as third;

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyTabs()
  ));
}

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  MyTabsState createState() => new MyTabsState();
}

class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {


  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Multi Colored Tab Bar'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          tabs: <Tab>[
            new Tab(text: 'First Tab'),
            new Tab(text: 'Second Tab'),
            new Tab(text: 'Third Tab'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          new first.First(),
          new second.Second(),
          new third.Third(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

/FirstTab.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class First extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red
    );
  }
}
```

/SecondTab.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Second extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue
    );
  }
}
```

/ThirdTab.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Third extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jang ! can you show us the code where you tried ?

Comment: Which kind of multi colored are you going for? Multiple color sections, a color hue, switching colors?

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, i added some detailed explanation and some codes, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will automatically set the `Scaffold` color on load and the tabs reflect the appropriate default colors.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TabBarApp(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarApp extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _TabBarAppState();
}

class _TabBarAppState extends State<TabBarApp>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _controller;
  List<TabData> _tabData;
  List<Tab> _tabs = [];
  List<Widget> _tabViews = [];
  Color _activeColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabData = [
      TabData(title: 'First Tab', color: Colors.red),
      TabData(title: 'Second Tab', color: Colors.green),
      TabData(title: 'Third Tab', color: Colors.blue),
    ];
    _activeColor = _tabData.first.color;
    _tabData.forEach((data) {
      final tab = Tab(
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          color: data.color,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(data.title),
          ),
        ),
      );
      _tabs.add(tab);

      final widget = Scaffold(backgroundColor: data.color);
      _tabViews.add(widget);
    });
    _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: _tabData.length)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _activeColor = _tabData[_controller.index].color;
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(primaryColor: _activeColor),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: _activeColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Multi Colored Tab Bar'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            indicatorColor: _activeColor,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            controller: _controller,
            tabs: _tabs,
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: _tabViews,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabData {
  TabData({this.title, this.color});

  final String title;
  final Color color;
}
```

Comment: This works but the unselected tabs have a minor space where the indicator comes. that is not being covered.
https://imgur.com/a/6v8y28O

Comment: `constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),` was the magic.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes it is possible try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './FirstTab.dart' as first;
import './SecondTab.dart' as second;
import 'ThirdTab.dart' as third;

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyTabs()
  ));
}

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  MyTabsState createState() => new MyTabsState();
}

class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {


  TabController controller;
  int tabIndex =0 ;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Multi Colored Tab Bar'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          indicator: BoxDecoration(color: setColor(tabIndex)),
          onTap: (index){
            setState(() {
              tabIndex = index;
            });
          },
          tabs: <Tab>[
            new Tab(text: 'First Tab'),
            new Tab(text: 'Second Tab'),
            new Tab(text: 'Third Tab'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          new first.First(),
          new second.Second(),
          new third.Third(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  setColor(int tabIndex){
    if(tabIndex == 0){
      return Colors.red;
    }else if(tabIndex == 1){
      return Colors.blue;
    }else if(tabIndex == 2){
      return Colors.yellow;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, it's really close. but is it possible to have it's color automatically as it is? i mean without pressing each tab. like the first tab has a default color of red, then second tab has a default color of blue, third tab has a default color of yellow.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing `primaryColor` in `theme` of `MaterialApp`, colour of Tab can be changed. So inside build method of `MyTabsState` return a `MaterialApp` & set it's `theme` to a variable *currentTabColor*.

Declare `currentTabColor` in `MyTabsState` & set it to `Colors.red`

Then set `onTap` to a callback which returns index of current tab & change state of `currentTabColor` using `if..else`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyTabs());
}

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyTabsState createState() => MyTabsState();
}

class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  Color currentTabColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentTabColor = Colors.red;
    controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: currentTabColor,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Multi Colored Tab Bar'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            onTap: (tabIndex) {
              if (tabIndex == 0)
                currentTabColor = Colors.red;
              else if (tabIndex == 1)
                currentTabColor = Colors.blue;
              else
                currentTabColor = Colors.green;
              setState(() {
                currentTabColor = currentTabColor;
              });
            },
            controller: controller,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              Tab(
                text: 'First Tab',
              ),
              Tab(text: 'Second Tab'),
              Tab(text: 'Third Tab'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: controller,
          children: <Widget>[
            Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
            Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
            Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.green),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: wow, didn't know it can be played like that, but is it possible to have each tab has their own default color? i mean without pressing anything they already have their own colors, like the first tab has a default color of red, then second tab has a default color of blue, third tab has a default color of yellow, so users can easily identify each tab by their color even at first glance.

Comment: Sounds tricky, but that will not look that good. In Google play app when you click on any tab, colour of tab & app-bar changes after that only. Initially all tabs have green colours.

Comment: thanks for looking into this, i learned a lot and this is a good start of what i envisioned it to be